# How to change Example.bat to Example.pl?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, scripting

I have read other threads [enter link description here](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/)that discuss .bat to L/unix conversions, but none has been satisfactory. I have also tried a lot of hack type approach in writing my own scripts.

I have the following example.bat script that is representative of the kind of script I want to run on unix.

Code:

```
echo "Example.bat"

perl script1 param.in newParam.in

perl script2 newParam.in stuff.D2D stuff.D2C

program.exe stuff.D2C

perl script3 stuff.DIS results.out
```

My problem is I don't know how to handle the perl and program.exe in the unix bash shell. I have tried putting them in a system(), but that did not work. Can someone please help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: Please include the code that you have already written and the errors that it returns.

Comment: Why would you not use a shell script for this? And the .exe will be your problem regardless.

Comment: To all above, I know, I know. I appreciate you asking this point. The problem is that when I run the above, it works in windows. However, when I use bash on my MacOSX, it "runs" but just reports data that isn't correct. So it is looking right, reporting no errors, and just messed up. Hence, my belief I need to manually convert it to a perl scrip that can run on Unix. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you have an executable file named `program.exe` somewhere in your `$PATH` (which you well might — Unix executables don't have to end in `.exe`, but nothing says they can't), the code you've pasted is a valid shell script.  If you save it in a file named, say, `example.bat`, you can run it by typing

```
sh example.bat
```

into the shell prompt.

Of course, Unix shell scripts are usually given the suffix `.sh` — or no suffix at all — rather than `.bat`.  Also, if you want your script to be executable directly, by typing just

```
example.sh
```

rather than `sh example.sh`, you need to do three things:

1. Start the script with a "shebang" line: a line that begins with `#!` and the full path to the shell interpreter you want to use to run it (e.g. `/bin/sh` for the basic Bourne shell), like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   echo "This is a shell script."

   # ... more commands here ...
   ```
2. Mark your script as executable using the `chmod` command, e.g.

   ```
   chmod a+rx example.sh
   ```
3. Put your script somewhere along your `$PATH`.  On Unix, the default path will not normally contain the current directory `.`, so you can't execute programs from the current directory just by typing their name.  You *can*, however, run them by specifying an explicit path, e.g.

   ```
   ./example.sh    # runs example.sh from the current directory
   ```

   To find out what your `$PATH` is, just type `echo $PATH` into the shell.